# Ruby version 2.7.0 is not supported in vercel

Tags: shopify, vercel

i was trying to deploy my shopify app in vercel but i was getting this error in vercel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update to Ruby 3.2.0. It works. Or at the very least, Ruby 3.1.3. No one uses older Ruby anymore hence that message.